# Look up overloaded operators in outer namespace in class design

Tags: c++

**How to let a wrapper class in a namespace know that in the outer/global namespace there may exist overloaded operators for the object that it wraps?**

*Note: I've heard of ADL, or Koenig lookup, but I met a real problem.*

**The Real Design Problem**

I want to design a header-only library. Say I put everything in namespace `my`. The part related to this question can be simplified to something like a template wrapper `item`.

```
// my.hpp

#include <iostream>

namespace my
{
    template<typename T>
    struct item
    {
        T thing;
        item(T t) : thing(t) {}
    };

    template<typename T>
    std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const item<T> & it)
    {
        os << it.thing;
        return os;
    }
}
```

With `item` what I want to achieve is that:

1. `item<T>` wraps a `T` object (with `T` object to be provided by user)
2. If `operator<<(std::ostream &, const T &)` is not defined in `<iostream>`, then I assume the user has overloaded `operator<<(std::ostream &, const T &)`, and I want `operator<<(std::ostream &, const item<T> &)` to call it.

**A Concrete User Example**

Consider a set of user code that does so for `T = std::vector<double>`

```
// user.hpp

// #include guard omitted

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &, const std::vector<double> &);
```

and

```
// user.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const std::vector<double> & v)
{
    for (const auto & e : v)
        os << e << " | ";
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> vec = {3.14, 2.83};
    std::cout << my::item<std::vector<double>>(vec);
}
```

Now if the user put

```
#include "user.hpp"
#include "my.hpp"
```

at the beginning of `user.cpp`, everything would be fine and `g++ user.cpp` would compile as expected.

However, if the user changed the order and put

```
#include "my.hpp"
#include "user.hpp"
```

the compiler would generate an error saying

```
my.hpp: In function 'std::ostream& my::operator<<(std::ostream&, const my::item<T>&)':
my.hpp:15:23: error: '::operator<<' has not been declared
```

Certainly I do not want the result to be dependent on the order of `#include`.

**My question is: As a designer of namespace `my` and wrapper `item<T>`, what can I do to `my` and `item<T>` so that `item<T>` can correctly spot and call `operator<<(std::ostream, const T &)` if it is provided by user?**

Thank you for your time!

**Update:** For your information, `g++ --version` returns

```
g++ (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 7.3.0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can I call function templates without forward declarations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674387/why-can-i-call-function-templates-without-forward-declarations)

Comment: This example shows it is bad to declare functions/operations whose parameters are all std entities as you cannot add such declarations into std to make use of ADL. In my opinion, it is the users' responsibility to avoid such functions/operations. He can however declare his new `Vector` class (may inherit `std::vector`) and declare operations on `Vector`.

Comment: @xskxzr Thank you! After some second thoughts, it became fully clear to me.

Comment: You need to fill in the answer.

Comment: @darune Thanks. Just did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*After reading a [question and answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255489/what-do-i-do-with-my-unanswered-questions-once-i-solve-it-by-myself) on meta, and following suggestions from comments, I am moving some "updates" in my own question and posting them formally as a self-answer. I am doing so in the hope that this will help someone in future who happen to meet the same kind of problem. Thank you!*

As @xskxzr correctly points out in the comment, there is something bad in the user code. To be specific,

> it is bad to declare functions/operations whose parameters are all `std` entities as you cannot add such declarations into std to make use of ADL

In this case, the problem lies on the side of the user, not on the designer.

Now if the user made a change

```
// user.hpp

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// CHANGE: (privately) inherit from std::vector<double>, rather than overload directly

struct DoubleVector : private std::vector<double>
{
    using std::vector<double>::vector;

    friend
    std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &, const DoubleVector &);
};

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &, const DoubleVector &);
```

and

```
// user.cpp

#include "my.hpp"
#include "user.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// CHANGE: use a user-defined DoubleVector class

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const DoubleVector & c)
{
    for (const auto & e : c)
        os << e << " | ";
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    DoubleVector vec = {3.14, 2.83};
    std::cout << my::item<DoubleVector>(vec);
}
```

Then the user code **would** compile regardless of the order of `#include "my.hpp"` and `#include "user.hpp"`.